# How to get Valuepath property of a asp.net treeview node using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Can Anyone help me with the following queries

1. How to get Valuepath property of a asp.net treeview node using
   Jquery?
2. How to insert a node in asp.net treeview control using Jquery?
3. How to delete a node from asp.net treeview control using Jquery?

I want to do these thing on client side using jQuery. Does any one have any idea, how to do these things.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your first question

1.How to get Valuepath property of a asp.net treeview node using Jquery?

Answer:

```
//**tvFolderStr** is the ID of TreeView. But in javascript it need embed with **_Data**

var selectedItem = tvFolderStr_Data.selectedNodeID.value;
var selectedNode = document.getElementById(selectedItem);
if (selectedNode != null) {
    var nodePath = selectedNode.href;  //result= "javascript:__doPostBack('tvFolderStr','sMyDoc-79\\test2-80')"
    //OR
    var nodePath = selectedNode.pathname;//result="__doPostBack('tvFolderStr','sMyDoc-79\\test2-80')"

    nodePath = nodePath.split(',')[1];
}
```

NodePath will contain valuePath. But it also conatins some other value as shown in sample result. You need to remove those unwanted text from nodePath variable.